# The listener and callback in Ext

Tags: javascript, extjs, listeners

I'm new in Ext, I see some codes in `Ext.onReady(...)`

```
tabItems.push({   
    id : 'schema-${form.schema.id}',
    title : '${form.description}',
    tabTip : '${form.description}',
    tooltipType: 'title',
    xtype : 'ttpanel',
    executeScripts : true,
    listeners : { load : initObjs, unload : unloadObjs, activate : ... },
    autoLoad : { url : 'selection.do',
            params : ...,
            scripts : true,
            callback : cb1
        }
    }
);
```

My question is, of:

1. `"load:initObjs"`,
2. `"callback:cb1"`,
3. page is rendered and user can operate it,

which of these three runs first? Why?

Thanks a million!

Comment: You could just set breakpoints in the code?

Comment: @Indianer, yes, i can set breakpoints, and page always get fully loaded after initObjs. The reason I asked this question is because some customers reported an error "cannot call method xxx of null", and it seems like page is fully loaded before initObjs.